# Blending two pictures together using Jython

Tags: python, jython, jes

I am tring to blend 2 pictures together and everytime I run this I get the error:

```
getPixel(picture,x,y): x (= 310) is less than 0 or bigger than the width (= 309)
```

The error value is:

```
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 18
```

I have resized the images multiple times to see if that would work and it does not. Any help would be great.

As of right now I have my pics are sized as follows:
Antelope=310x369
Jackolope=250x341

```
def blendPictures():                #define a new function
  Pic1=makePicture(pickAFile())     #Pick Pic1 Antelope(Barb)
  Pic2=makePicture(pickAFile())     #Pick Pic2 Jackalope(Katie)
  canvas=makeEmptyPicture(640,480)  #Create an empty picture file
  sourceX=0
  for targetX in range(0,150):      #Let's ad our first loop
    sourceY=0
    for targetY in range(0,getHeight(Pic1)):
      color = getColor(getPixel(Pic1,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY),color)
      sourceY = sourceY + 1
    sourceX = sourceX +1
  overlap = getWidth(Pic1)-150
  sourceX=0
  for targetX in range(150,getHeight(Pic1)):
    sourceY=0
    for targetY in range(0,getHeight(Pic2)):
      APixel = getPixel(Pic1,sourceX+150,sourceY)
      BPixel = getPixel(Pic2,sourceX,sourceY)
      newRed=0.50*getRed(APixel)+0.50*getRed(BPixel)
      newGreen=0.50*getGreen(APixel)+0.50*getGreen(BPixel)
      newBlue=0.50*getBlue(APixel)+0.50*getBlue(BPixel)
      color=makeColor(newRed,newGreen,newBlue)
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY),color)
      sourceY=sourceY+1
    sourceX=sourceX+1
  sourceX=overlap
  for targetX in range(150+overlap,150+getWidth(Pic2)):
    sourceY=0
    for targetY in range(0,getHeight(Pic2)):
       color=getColor(getPixel(Pic2,sourceX,sourceY))
       setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY),color)
       sourceY=sourceY+1
    sourceX=sourceX+1
  show(canvas)
  return canvas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do,
but one obvious issue is your second loop section:

```
for targetX in range(150, getHeight(Pic1)):
```

This should be:

```
for targetX in range(150, getWidth(Pic1)):
```

Otherwise, you loop 219 times (369-150) in the x direction,
which will cause the mentioned error in the line:

```
APixel = getPixel(Pic1, sourceX+150, sourceY)
```

Because in iteration 160 of 219, the code will try `getPixel(Pic1, 310, 0)`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that you pointed it out it is very obvious. I don't know how long I have been looking at this code and couldn't figure it out. Works perfect now. just need to get a Different picture so it looks better. Again Thank you very much SMeyer